# My c++ program fails around 3or4 out of 15 designated test runs and its quite a simple one so im at a loss

Tags: c++, function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    float a, b, l, x;
    cin >> l;
    cin >> x;
    a = (x / 100) * l;
    a = round(a);
    b = a - 1;
    if (b <= 0) {
        cout << 1;
    }
    else {
        cout << b;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The task at hand is:
There are L assigned seats  1<l<1000
And only X percent of those seats can be used 1<x<100
The result **must** be smaller than x percent

I tried the above program and it ran 11 out of the 15 test cases needed, i tried modifying the program to find out whats wrong and i found out the remaining 4 cases can be solved if i use the ceil function instead of round but then some other cases get wrong answer and im out of ideas.

**Some failing testcases**

Depending if or not you keep the `b = a - 1;` correction, either one or the other test fails:
`l = 133, x = 49`: correct result 66, wrong result 65
`l = 133, x = 100`: correct result 0, wrong result 1

Comment: Shouldn't the result be 0 if b is 0? Difficult to know without a full problem statement. My guess would be you need to be a little more careful with your calculations, e.g. you would round 2.4 to 2 then subtract 1 but 2 would be correct as the nearest while number less than 2.4

Comment: If I input l=100 and x = 50 I get 49 as a result even though it should be 50, right? If so, try using the `floor()` function and then don't substract 1

Comment: @muhman it should be 49 it always has to be smaller than the x%,atleast thats the example im given

Comment: @Alan Birtles that part i added in hopes of something changing but the results stayed the same with and without it so i just sent the code with that part included.

Comment: It looks like the problem description is missing some details.

Answer (score 0):

Seats are better represented with integral types (What is a half occupied seat?). You can then also take advantage of integer arithmetic: Integer division auto-floor the result.

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int freeSeats, usedSeats, allSeats;
    float usedPercentage;
    cin >> allSeats;
    cin >> usedPercentage;
    freeSeats = (allSeats * (100.0 - usedPercentage)) / 100;
    usedSeats = allSeats-freeSeats;
    cout << usedSeats;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But when allSeats = 100 and usedPercentage = 50, usedSeats is gonna be 50 - which is incorrect according to his comment above